# Multiple autovacuum: ANALYZE/VACUUM on the same table

Tags: postgresql

I am currently using Postgres 11. For some reason whenever I check running autovacuums, I would see several multiple `autovacuum: ANALYZE` or `autovacuum: VACUUM` on the same table.

```
postgres=# SELECT backend_type,
  pid,
  now() - xact_start AS duration,
  query,
  state
FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE query LIKE 'autovacuum%'
ORDER BY duration DESC LIMIT 64;
   backend_type    | pid  |    duration     |                               query                               | state
-------------------+------+-----------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+--------
 autovacuum worker | 5900 | 00:48:29.175656 | autovacuum: ANALYZE someschema.foo                      | active
 autovacuum worker | 3552 | 00:48:18.72438  | autovacuum: ANALYZE someschema.foo                                  | active
 autovacuum worker | 6122 | 00:47:29.907655 | autovacuum: VACUUM someschema.foo                            | active
 autovacuum worker | 5897 | 00:42:45.380395 | autovacuum: VACUUM someschema.bar                            | active
 autovacuum worker | 5583 | 00:38:45.406516 | autovacuum: VACUUM someschema.bar                          | active
```

The DDL looks like the following:

```
                                  Table "someschema.foo"
      Column       | Type | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage  | Stats target | Description
-------------------+------+-----------+----------+---------+----------+--------------+-------------
 foo_id    | text |           | not null |         | extended |              |
 baz_id | text |           |          |         | extended |              |
Indexes:
    "foo_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (foo_id)
    "baz_reference_id_idx" UNIQUE, btree (foo_id, baz_id)
Options: autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit=2000, autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay=10
```

I am unsure what is going on, and I cannot find my answers from the official documentations:

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/routine-vacuuming.html#AUTOVACUUM
- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-analyze.html

```
max_worker_processes = 15
autovacuum_max_workers = 64
```

Comment: how many autovacuum_max_workers you are running on the server?
can you add backed_type in your query so that we will know if its parallel or not

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please extend your question to include the DDL of the table that is vacuumed (is it by any chance a partitioned table?) and include the outcome of query "show autovacuum_max_workers ;" and "show max_worker_processes;"

Comment: @Cninroh, I added `backend_type`.

@NikhilB I added the current values for those options